# CrystalDiskInfo - PC randomly crashes while playing games, trying to figure out cause

Tags: crash, windows-11, crystaldiskinfo

D Drive:

[image: D Drive]

C Drive:

[image: C Drive]

I've been having pc freezing and crashing while playing video games and doing normal tasks on my computer over the last few months. I've tried everything I could think of and memory tests. I was hoping if someone could help me understand what CrystalDiskInfo is saying about my drives. The explanations I've found online aren't that clear.

Bios:

[image: Bios]

Answer (score 0):

Check in Windows logs what is the reason or device from which the crashes happen.

Also you need CPU and RAM frequencies and timings to be set properly. If they are timed too fast - that would be the reason.

CrystalDiskInfo does not say anything bad in the screenshots. Seems like drives are used but not failing.

EDIT: so in result, from comments, seems like OP have a little too low power for the whole computer (460 W for 2060 graphic card and 9700K processor). In temporary high demand the PSU can be not supplying enough power.

Comment: I think I misworded a bit, it never crashes. The screen just freezes and I have to hold down the power button for it to turn off. This has been going on for months. How do I look at my CPU and RAM frequencies?

Comment: @Justin that's a freeze which is equal to crash. Mostly overheating. Frequencies you have in BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/637291213673857044/1031037100096757850/87366FE8-9CD8-4019-82D4-BA2EF36C3BF3.jpg?size=4096

I just went through my bios settings and didnt find anything related to frequencies

Comment: @Justin is it desktop or laptop? On desktop you must have that options. I cannot open the link you provided.

Comment: Its a desktop, I added the picture to the original message

Comment: @Justin you need to search for frequencies and timings in these expandable options. Then set them to correct hardware values.

Comment: I have went through all of it, there is nothing that talks about CPU or RAM frequencies

Comment: I just rechecked everything checking both f2 and f12 and there is nothing related to it. Any ideas?

Comment: @Justin You must have CPU/RAM timings in BIOS, need to search for them and understand them. You have no other option. Refill your knowledge. I had the same problem with badly set freq.

Comment: @Justin Frequencies are "40x" and sth like "100 MHz", timings are like 19-21-21-41. They must be set to hardware characteristics. Maybe "Performance" option.

Comment: I still cannot find and I did some research Dell G5 doesnt let you change ram speed in the bios. I used some software and found my ram speed is 1333Mhz (two 8gb sticks) and the timings are 19-19-19-43

Comment: I also did some testing on the hardware side. I unplugged my hdd from the motherboard and after some testing I still crashed. I have also believe my PSU is short circuiting because I still hear a very faint sound even when the PC is turned off. Do you think that is likely to be the problem?

Comment: @Justin I think this is overheating problem.

Comment: I have some software that Ill use to check the temperatures while I am playing games on my second monitor, Ill let you know what the values are the next time I crash.

Comment: @Justin https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Dell-g5-5500-overheating-and-random-shutdown/td-p/7917508

Comment: I dont have a laptop. I switched my power supply and the crashes have gone down a lot. But I still had it happen twice in the last few days (It used to happen atleast once or twice a day). I did a CPU and GPU stress test and had no issues with over heating

Comment: @Justin Have you checked Windows logs? Event Viewer?

Comment: No I have not. What exactly do I need to look for there?

Also I forgot to mention that the type of freezing has changed before my mouse cursor wasnt moving but the last two crashes I have been able to move it while the screen is frozen.

Comment: @Justin Windows logs = Event Viewer should tell you why the system freezes.

Comment: In window logs I see critical error Kernal Power Unexpected shutdown. Thats me turning off my computer while its freezing. What exactly am I supposed to look at?

Comment: @Justin and that's the reason the computer is freezing. This can tell that the reason is not enough power from PSU.

Comment: "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly." That is the description. I have a 460W PSU with a 2060 and a i7 9700k, Im pretty sure this is enough power. (I also switched my PSU a few days ago)

Comment: @Justin seems like you know better than me. That's great! You can solve your problem by yourself.